# How do I discriminate between user input sent to my processing.php page from my form page vs any other form page?

Tags: php

Basically, I am trying to prevent my processing page from processing forms from sources other than my own.

my form

```
<form action='processing.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='first' value='firstname'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
```

their form

```
<form action='processing.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='first' value='firstname'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
```

How can I make sure I'm only processing forms sent from my form, or can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (and its a good reflex to think about it) by creating a unique token and then using that token to validate the origin.

This is actually one way of preventing [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) attack.

You can store that token on your server when you generate the form page (for example in the session), output it in your form and then validate it upon submission.

So you could do something like :

```
<?php
// Generate token
$_SESSION['csrfToken'] = hash('sha256', uniqid());
```

In the form :

```
<form> 
<?php
// Render token inside form 
echo '<input type="hidden" name="tk" id="tk" value="' . $_SESSION['csrfToken'] . " />';

....
```

Then validate :

```
<?php
// Do your validation inside the submission
if ($_SESSION['csrfToken'] !== $_POST['tk']) 
{
     // Error ...
}
```